# Id cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

i write the simple android code for one activity and provided its view by xml file named as second.xml in layout folder.I have mentioned this activity also in mainfiest file.But i am facing the error of that "second cannot be resolved or it is not a field" at setContentView method.
Please give the solution

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Second extends Activity
{
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        // Intent i=getIntent();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should edit the question and put the code with question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to Clean your project from *Project->Clean* and also remove *import android.R;* from Second  before cleaning it.make sure you have second.xml file under *src/layout/second.xml*.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Second extends Activity
{
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

    //      Intent i=getIntent();
  }
}
```

Comment: What you did wrong: You imported the wrong R class. you should always put the R class generated in your solution in your imports, not android.R. I hope this clarified what exactly went wrong so it won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove  the this imported line

```
import android.R;
```

then  clean just like this:

Go to **Project>> clean** the project. I think you might be solve your problem;
Go to more details:  [R can not resolve](http://google-androidlovers.blogspot.com/search/label/R%20cannot%20be%20resolved%20to%20a%20variable)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `import android.R;` and clean your project. You should import android.R only when you are trying to use Android provided data. For example, to display a listview with single row you would use the Android provided layout and textview as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```